# Racket not closing TCP port

Tags: racket

I've written a simple HTTP echo server in Racket. When I run the server from within DrRacket and then click the Stop button, my program terminates, but the port that was being used takes an annoyingly long time to close. If I run `lsof -i :<port>` in my terminal after terminating the program, I don't see anything bound to that port, but DrRacket disagrees and refuses to let me restart my program, telling me that something is already bound to that port.

Is this a bug in Racket, or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: What code are you using to start the webserver? Have you looked at [More: Systems Programming with Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/more/index.html#%28part._top%29). It describes how to implement threading and custodians to avoid the class of problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `tcp-listen` directly (meaning that you handle all the low-level socket stuff yourself, and manually handle HTTP too), you need to call it with the `reuse?` parameter set to `#t`.

If you are using the `web-server` module, it already sets `reuse?` to `#t` so it should already work.